# How to get Grid DataSource

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid to show data.
In that grid I implement a paging as well. when I take the data count and some column values it showing only current page values. I need to get whole data in that grid. I use following code to get that records.

To take row count : 
var mya = new Array();
mya = grid.getDataIDs();

To take specific column values :

uniqueTexts = []
uniqueTexts = $("#list").jqGrid("getCol", uniqueNames);

And All this functions are working with only after given alert box on that values.

It's great pleasure any one can help this.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't posted enough JavaScript code which could show what you do. So I try to guess. I suppose that you use either `datatype: "local"` or `datatype: "json"` with `loadonce: true`. In both cases all the data (all pages) will be loaded in the grid and the paging are implemented *locally*. In the case you can get the total number of items in the grid in the following way:

```js
var data = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
alert("The total number of items in the grid: " +
    data == null ? "unknown" : data.length);
```